# Arrays as function parameters in numba

Tags: python, numba

Following simple example fails with an error:

Standalone module:

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('foo')

@cc.export('product','float64(float64[:], float64[:])')
def product(a, b):
    prod = 0
    for i in range(a.size):
        prod += a[i] * b[i]
    return prod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

The test program:

```
import numpy as np
import foo

x = np.array([2,3,1,0])
y = np.array([2,3,1,0])

print(foo.product(x,y))
```

Fails with error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\temp\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(foo.product(x,y))
SystemError: exception RuntimeError<class 'BytesWarning'> not a BaseException subclass
```

Used numba version is 0.42.0 and Python 3.7.2 on Windows.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally got your code to work:

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('foo')
cc.verbose = True
@cc.export('producti','int64(int64[:], int64[:])')  #<--- Your data type was wrong
def product(a, b):
    prod = 0
    for i in range(a.size):
        y = a[i] * b[i]
        prod += y
    return prod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

Code to test the above function:

```
import numpy as np
import foo

x = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0])
y = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0])

print(foo.producti(x, y))   # Output : 14
```

**Some points to note here**:

- The way you are creating your `x` and `y` arrays, the dtype is set to `int64` by default, so when you are typecasting it into `float64` it is being incorrectly converted.

> print(x.dtype)
>
> Output : dtype('int64')

- So, simply fixing your types to `int64` does the trick here(or you can use `i8` as shorthand if you want).
- **Link to google Colab notebook with running code** : [Notebook Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XYstdkUF5FAcQQgdK_t_tKQ2UhAtPfGb)

**References**:

- [Numba types](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html#numba-types)